# Textfield position shifts up after making a selection MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this `Autocomplete` component, it renders a `TextField` with options to select from , problem is once I make a selection, it losses margin top, my bet is on the text, since there is no text there is no margin! I partially solved it by add in a empty space, which proves my point but still what is the right way to solve this, any idea how to stop this from happening and yet be able to pass an empty text without losing the margin.

[image: Codesandbox Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because of the label, you set the `label` to an empty string whenever there is a selected value:

```
label={selected.item === "" ? "test" : ""}
```

Which affects the following rule:

```
label + .MuiInput-formControl {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

If the label is empty, it will be removed from the DOM, so `margin-top` doesn't get applied anymore. A simple workaround is simply set the label to a non-empty string even if you don't want to display it:

```
label={selected.item === "" ? "test" : " "}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `placeholder` props to the `TextField` component inside `Autocomplete` rather than conditional `label` props.

And then if you want to add margin, you can add some styling to the `Autocomplete` component like `style={{marginTop:20}}` or using MUI `makeStyles` API.
https://v4.mui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook

```
      ...
      <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        key={bool}
        options={arr}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
        onChange={handleChange}
        style={{marginTop: 20}} // or using makeStyles
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            placeholder="test" //label="test"
          />
        )}
      />
      ...
```